# Dropdown with search filter in codeigniter (i am using form_dropdown)

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter form_dropdown to populate list of countries but i want my dropdown list with a searchtext field so that user can easily filter by typing in that search field.

```
<?php
  echo form_dropdown('country_id', $countryList, '', "class='form-control country_list' id='country_id'");
?>
```

Comment: try [Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use select2 to make your dropdown with search filter

```
$(document).ready(function () {     

    $(".country_list").select2({
            placeholder: " -- Select Your Country -- "
    });
});
```

[image]